# Can we use "if else" in "Check" constraint in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Can i use if else under a check constraint.

Can i use check constraint using a variable

need xplanation with eg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `IF/ELSE`, but you can use inline conditionals: `CASE WHEN`

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit vague. What are you trying to do with the IF...ELSE? Check constraints aren't processed code, they're part of the table definition - there is no control flow and no variables. You can use a user-defined function in check constraints, which may be what you're after, but it's hard to tell from your question.